# IntelliJ IDEA reorganizing dependencies

Tags: intellij-idea, android-gradle-plugin

I'm developing for Android and have downloaded IDEA  13.1.3. The reason for that was the missing option in Android Studio to reorganize dependencies.

`I'm going to ProjectStructure -> Modules -> MyModule -> Dependencies`

But every time gradle rebuilds the project the imports are automatically reorganized bringing the `Android API` as the first dependency (i.e. the `MyApp.iml` is modified and  `<orderEntry type="jdk" jdkName="Android API 19 Platform" jdkType="Android SDK" />` is moved to the top.

Additionally the project SDK is being changed to java (i.e. `.idea\misc.xml` is modified)

I'm using the latest InetelliJ Community Edition RC - that is `v 13.1.3` `build 135.909`. I've tried android gradle plugin `0.9.+` and the most recent `0.10.4`

Answer (score 0):

For Gradle-based projects, setting order of entries in the classpath is not supported at this time.  As you've seen, for Gradle-based projects it rewrites the .iml files every time it syncs the project with the Gradle files, which happens frequently. In this scenario, the .iml project files aren't considered to be user-editable and aren't intended to be checked into source control or treated as anything other than ephemeral. The same goes for everything in the .idea folder.

Where this is usually a problem for Android Studio users is for those who want to do plain Java unit testing (rather than the androidTest support in the Android Gradle plugin). This is known to not work very well at this time; you can track its progress at https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=65186. I realize that bug doesn't mention anything specifically about classpath ordering, but it's all part of the same larger issue.